# Average dataframe rows for unique combinations of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns "x", "y", "z", "result" (and a few other columns.)

How can I produce a dataframe such that:

1. There is only one row for each unique combination of x,y, and z
2. The values in each columns for a row are the averages of the column values for all rows in the initial dataframe with that specific x,y, and z.

Comment: What have you tried so far. What was your resoning?

Comment: I've tried searching the internet for a quick answer, then I tried asking a question on stack overflow.  My reasoning was that there was likely a byzantine pandas one or two liner that someone else would know and I could get on with other things until a helpful soul came up with it.

If it weren't for the internet, I would use zip on the three columns, call np.unique on it, loop through the unique combinations, select all rows with those x,y,z; mean, then concat all of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` and take `mean`:

```
df.groupby(['x', 'y', 'z']).mean()
```

P.S. And you can pass `as_index=False` parameter to `groupby` if you want `x`, `y` and `z` to remain as columns instead of a MultiIndex.